# VBA vlookup with excel Events

Tags: vba, excel, events

I have a list of places in `Sheet1 column D` and a list of original values in `Sheet1 column E`. There are blank rows in between some of the places and some places are repeated.

I have a condensed list of places in `Sheet2 Column F` (with 1 blank row in the data) and In `Sheet2 column G` I can put new corrected values for each place.

The plan is to have a script that will run every time i put a new value in `Sheet2 column G`. This I hope can be achieved with excel vba Events. Say I update `G5`, the script will find `Sheet2 F5` in `Sheet1 D:D` and then replace the corresponding value in `Sheet1 E:E` with the new `Sheet2 G5` value:

Here is my attempt at some code but i'm still not sure 1) how to make this work and 2) how to make it work every time I update a value in `Sheet2 G:G`? Any help would be really appreciated.

```
Sub CorrectingValues()

Dim i As Long
Dim lstrw As Long
Dim newval As Range

Sheets("Sheet1").activate
lstrw = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For i = lstrw to 1 Step -1
    If Sheet("2").Cells(i, "G").value <>"" Then
        newval = .Find(Sheets("Sheet2").cells(i, "F") _
                  After:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1") , LookIn:=xlValues)
        Cells(newval, "E").Value = Sheets("2").cells(i,"G")
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the below code in Sheet2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("G:G")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        enteredvalue = Target.Value
        enteredvaluefind = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1)
        targetfindrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D").Find(enteredvaluefind).Row
        targetfindcolumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D").Find(enteredvaluefind).Column
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(targetfindrow, targetfindcolumn + 1) = enteredvalue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir, this is a godly formula that works perfectly, thank you so much! So I can better learn from it could you give a brief explanation of the application.intersect function and also how you can use target as a variable without having "Dim Target As..."? Thanks again

Comment: @IIJHFII, The Intersect Method will return a Range Object that represents the intersection of two, or more, ranges. It can be used to determine if a specified Range Object intersects another specified range(s).
so,
if intersection happens within the selected range (G:G) then this code will work and get the target corresponding location and search for the same in sheet1 and update.

Nothing will happen, if it does not interesect.

Target is nothing but the changes made in Sheet2 cells.

Answer (score 1):

### "Excel event"

To do something when something change in column `G`: to be done in the Worksheet VBA where you want to capture changes:

a) declare a global variable to reuse what changed, just in case:

```
Dim RangeSupp As Range
```

b)  VBA Event when something changes in Excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set RangeSupp = Target
    ' check what changed
    If InStr(Target.Address, "$H") = 1 Then
        ' call the function you want
        GoToAnotherMacro RangeSupp
    End If
End Sub
```

c) example of the function I called for my tests

```
Sub GoToAnotherMacro(Target As Range)
MsgBox Target.Address
End Sub
```